# Memory issues in Cpp

Tags: c++, memory

I have several questions:

1) When I statically allocate array of 1 000 000 int, I got stack overflow error:

```
int temp1[48][48];
int im2 [1000000];
int step = 8;
int lcol, lrow;
....
```

Although, `1000000*sizeof(int)=4 000 000` < 4 Mb. And I have about 8 GB of RAM.

2) What happens when I use dynamical allocation (new and Malloc functions) and forget to delete my memory? Will my future compilations be affected by memory leakages from the past compilations?

3) If yes, how can I fix it? Should I close and open visual studio, or I have to reboot my PC?

4) If I use dynamical allocations with corresponding delete operations correctly, but I work in debug mode (step by step compilation) and I compiled "new" command and didn't compile "delete" command, will there be a memory leakage?

Comment: memory for your array is allocated out of heap, not stack... stack overflow suggests there is something else going on in the code that maybe you didn't share? Did you try changing to 1000 ints and see if that works? increase 10x at a time and see if that's indeed what is breaking?

Comment: The stack size of a program is limited, use dynamic allocation for `im2`, or even better `std::vector<int> im2;` that handles this for you correctly.

Comment: When I change 1M to 100k everything works

Comment: @Mihon _"When I change 1M to 100k ..."_ Yes, I just told you the stack has a certain limit.

Comment: Compilation has nothing to do with execution. Once your compiled program stops, the Operating System reclaims all memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not unusual for platforms to have limitations on stack size.

On every modern platform you are likely to use, a process' address space ceases to exist as soon as it terminates. So there's no need to do anything about leaks of allocated address space, backed or unbacked, across process termination. The address space ceases to exist because it belongs to the process.

If you allocate without deleting, that address space will be wasted until the program terminates. In significant amounts, this can create performance problems and resource consumption problems.

Comment: Thanks, so I don't have to worry - after program terminate, memory is released automatically. I have Visual Studio 2013, windows 7 btw.

Comment: Exactly. When a process terminates, its entire address space is released, including releasing any pages backed by physical memory.

Comment: Windows and Linux don't have limitation on stack size (well - not up to 1 GB at least); just that common compilers default to having a stack on the order of 1MB. The compilers let you change this via a switch.

Comment: @Mihon It might not be. I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your symptoms , these lines are inside a function:

```
int temp1[48][48];
int im2 [1000000];
```

so they are not static. The C term for this sort of storage is *automatic*. You could make them static by using the `static` keyword, which will make them not subject to stack overflow. It is not required to use `malloc` here, although that is an option.